# Google earth deviation from arcgis 10 based maps

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I really need your help.. I am using arcgis 10 and i mapped some points. with the based maps provided, i tried digitizing the road network. When i exported to kmz file and opened it in google eath. there is a shift. is it that i am not doing something right

Comment: Have you set your projection to Geographic WGS84?

Comment: can you please quantify the shift - is it a few metres off, or are your features sitting on the wrong continent? Can you give some screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this shift is due to a projection or datum issue. Check the projection of the feature class you created in ArcMap (the one you converted to a kmz), and make sure it is projected to WGS '84 Web Merc. Aux. Sphere. Also, do you know about the OpenStreetMap project which provides similar data for free?

Comment: This could be true, but also there could be a difference between the two ortho photos.  If it is a small shift, it is photo related.  If it is bigger (more than 6 feet) @mlowry is right, it is a projection issue.